# Spark (Scala) Pairwise subtract all rows in data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame that looks something along the lines of:

```
+-----+-----+------+-----+
|col1 |col2 |col3  |col4 |
+-----+-----+------+-----+
|1.1  |2.3  |10.0  |1    |
|2.2  |1.5  |5.0   |1    |
|3.3  |1.3  |1.5   |1    |
|4.4  |0.5  |7.0   |1    |
|5.5  |1.2  |8.1   |2    |
|6.6  |2.3  |8.2   |2    |
|7.7  |4.5  |10.3  |2    |
+-----+-----+------+-----+
```

I would like to subtract each row from the row above but only if they have the same entry in col4, so 2-1, 3-2 but not 5-4. Also col4 should not be changed, so the result would be

```
+-----+-----+------+------+
|col1 |col2 |col3  |col4  |
+-----+-----+------+------+
|1.1  |-0.8 |-5.0  |1     |
|1.1  |-0.2 |-3.5  |1     |
|1.1  |-0.8 |5.5   |1     |
|1.1  |1.1  |0.1   |2     |
|1.1  |2.2  |2.1   |2     |
+-----+-----+------+------+
```

This sounds like it'd be simple, but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: How would you identify "the row above"? In general Spark's dataframes do not have an intrinsic order.

Comment: any clue as to why no response to answers pls

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using [spark-sql](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically) i.e. creating a temporary view with your dataframe and applying the following sql. It uses window functions `LAG` to subtract the previous row value ordered by `col1` and partitioned by `col4`. The first row value in each group partitioned by `col4` is identified using `row_number` and filtered.

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView('my_temp_view')

results = sparkSession.sql('<insert sql below here>')
```

```sql
SELECT
     col1,
     col2,
     col3,
     col4
FROM (
SELECT
    (col1 - (LAG(col1,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY col4 ORDER BY col1) )) as col1,
    (col2 - (LAG(col2,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY col4 ORDER BY col1) )) as col2,
    (col3 - (LAG(col3,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY col4 ORDER BY col1) )) as col3,
    col4,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col4 ORDER BY col1) rn
FROM
    my_temp_view
) t 
WHERE rn <> 1
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZMpH1mZ28RwsZTtwV3d3U/0)

Answer (score 0):

Here just the idea with a self-JOIN based on RDD with zipWithIndex and back to DF - some overhead, that you can tailor, *z* being your *col4*.

At scale I am not sure about the performance that Catalyst Optimizer will apply, I looked at .explain(true); not convinced entirely, but I find it hard to interpret the output sometimes. Ordering of data is guaranteed.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq( (1.0, 2.0, 1), (0.0, -1.0, 1), (3.0, 4.0, 1), (6.0, -2.3, 4))).toDF("x", "y", "z")
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))

val rddWithId = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
val dfZippedWithId =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)

dfZippedWithId.show(false)
dfZippedWithId.printSchema()

val res = dfZippedWithId.as("dfZ1").join(dfZippedWithId.as("dfZ2"), $"dfZ1.z" ===  $"dfZ2.z" &&
                                                                    $"dfZ1.rowid" ===  $"dfZ2.rowid" -1
                                                                   ,"inner")
                        .withColumn("newx", $"dfZ2.x" - $"dfZ1.x")//.explain(true)

res.show(false)
```

returns the input:

```
+---+----+---+-----+
|x  |y   |z  |rowid|
+---+----+---+-----+
|1.0|2.0 |1  |0    |
|0.0|-1.0|1  |1    |
|3.0|4.0 |1  |2    |
|6.0|-2.3|4  |3    |
+---+----+---+-----+
```

and the result which you can tailor by selecting and adding extra calculations:

```
+---+----+---+-----+---+----+---+-----+----+
|x  |y   |z  |rowid|x  |y   |z  |rowid|newx|
+---+----+---+-----+---+----+---+-----+----+
|1.0|2.0 |1  |0    |0.0|-1.0|1  |1    |-1.0|
|0.0|-1.0|1  |1    |3.0|4.0 |1  |2    |3.0 |
+---+----+---+-----+---+----+---+-----+----+
```